# C++ style glob() function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I know that the `glob()` function is available to search for a file pattern on POSIX systems. This is a C style function however, providing a `char **` of results.

Is there a C++ style equivalent function to `glob()` (I couldn't find anything under Boost or C++11 references)? What I want is something that returns some type of collection of paths as strings.

Comment: How about writing your own wrapper?

Comment: You'll have to write a wrapper around boost::filesystem

Comment: I guess I could write a wrapper, but was just wondering if its been done before in some type of standard library.